# Conditional formatting on Excel 2007, need to add formula

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have to show 3 conditions using Conditional formatting.

If the % change in the cost driver is more than .25% higher or lower than the % change in actual price.

```
More than .25% - Red
Less than .25% - Green
In between - Yellow
```

I'm able to get the first two, but not the third one. 
For Green, I used this formula - =if(1.30-1.40/1.30)-(1,210-1,170/1,210)<.25, For Red =if(1.30-1.40/1.30)-(1,210-1,170/1,210)>.25

I tried using Between and Median for Yellow (-0.25% and 0.25%), but does not seem to be working.

```
Product  Location   Jul-13  Aug-13  Sep-13  Oct-13
1         A         1.40    1.30    1.34    1.47
2         B         1.43    1.43    1.46    1.47
3         C         1.40    1.41    1.45    1.46

Driver             1,170    1,210   1,260   1,225
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've got the wrong end of the stick here, it looks to me as though you currently have:

for red: if < -0.25%
for green:  if > 0.25%
for yellow: if (<= 0.25% OR >= -0.25%)

None of the data you provided match the condition for yellow, hence you aren't getting any results.

Using E17 and F17 as the demo cells, you could do:

`=IF(AND((F12-E12)/E12*100<=0.25,(F12-E12)/E12*100>=-0.25),"Yellow",IF((F12-E12)/E12*100>0.25,"Green",IF((F12-E12)/E12*100<-0.25,"Red")))`

If E17 is 1170 and F17 is 1171 you will have "Yellow" output. 0.25% higher or lower you will have "Green" or "Red" output respectively.  You can use text conditional formatting from the word.

Comment: Thanks. For Yellow, the condition is if between -0.25% and 0.25%. Tried with median, that also does not seem to be working. If you can tell me the exact formula, would be great.

Comment: Thanks so much. I need to do this in Excel 2007, can you please advise how do I put the yellow condition in that case.